# What software or service should I use for indexing my massive sound effects libraries?

Tags: sound-effects, sfx, mac, soundminer

I am looking for a software or service to index/search similar to soundminer, but simpler (just metadata indexing/search with automatic indexing of new content).

At this point, we simply search for keywords using finder's search function.

We are not interested in Soundminer because of it's price point, as well as it's busy UI and learning curve. A simpler database search would be better.

I work in a production house with other 10 producers. We all share our sfx libraries in a remote server, which is accessed by VPN and SMB protocol. The libraries, loops and samples add up to several TBs, so local network for every producer is not feasible

All producers use macOS and the server is accessed by VPN and Samba.

Possible Solutions:

- Populating an excel spreadsheet using unix commands, and searching that spreadsheet instead of the files.
- Creating a MySQL database, but that would entail creating a web API for the non tech savvy producers
- Maybe using soundminer web?
- Manually creating PDFs with the metadata of the files (please no)
- Biting the bullet and upgrading to Soundminer.

This is my first question in any stack overflow/stack exchange websites, so all feedback is appreciated! English is also not my first language, so I apologize in advance!

Thank you!

Comment: Try MetaDigger, but it doesn't support networking

Comment: I'm also very interested to know what methods/solutions you may find (Did you faind any btw ?) since I'm actually going through my whole pro & personnal sound library. Have you checked out the UCS, Universal Category System, website ? https://universalcategorysystem.com/ Curious to see what answers you may find !

Comment: Can you please give some examples, added to your question, illustrating the indexing and retrieval process? Thanks